# Donsker's Invariance Principle and Gambler's Ruin

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $(S_{n})_{n\geq0}$ be a Random Walk (i.e. $S_{n}:=X_{1}+\cdots+X_{n}$, where $\mathbb{P}(X_{i}=1)=\mathbb{P}(X_{i}=-1)=1/2$). Define interpolated random walks $(S^{n}(t))_{t\in\left[0,1\right]}$ by

$S^{n}(t):=n^{-1/2}\left(S_{\left\lfloor nt\right\rfloor }+(nt-\left\lfloor nt\right\rfloor )X_{\left\lfloor nt\right\rfloor +1}\right)$.

Let $(B(t))_{t\in\left[0,1\right]}$ be a standard Brownian Motion. Then Donsker's Invariance Principle says that, for any bounded uniformly continuous function $f$, we have $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{E}\left[f(S^{n}(\cdot))\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[f(B(\cdot))\right]$.

For $x\in C([0,1])$, define $f(x):=\mathbf{1}_{\left\{ \max_{t\in\left[0,1\right]}\left|x(t)\right|\leq1\right\} }$. Then $f$ is uniformly continuous and bounded, so we get $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{P}\left(\max_{t\in\left[0,1\right]}\left|S^{n}(t)\right|\leq1\right)=\mathbb{P}\left(\max_{t\in\left[0,1\right]}\left|B(t)\right|\leq1\right)$. I have read that this should be related to the “Gambler's Ruin” problem, but I fail to see the connection. Can anyone give me a pointer?